# Why show that $\int f g = \psi(g)$ holds for $\psi \in (L^q)'$ and for all $g \in L^\infty$ in the proof of isomorphism between $L^p$ and $(L^q)'$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, duality-theorems

I'm studying the proof that $T_f(g) := \int f g \, d\mu$ is a bijective isomorphism between
$L^p$ and $L^q \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $1/p + 1/q = 1$. My question is about the proof of the surjectivity, wherein we want show the existence of
a function $f \in L^q$ for all continuous linear operators $\psi : L^q \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T_f = \psi$.

The proof in question is Theorem 6.16 (p. 128) in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", but I have found near identical proofs in Elstrodt's "Measure- and Integration-theory" (p.312) (German) and in [these](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/real-an/4-06-dual-lp.pdf) lecture notes on real analysis.

I now provide a rough sketch of the proof. We first work on the case where $\mu(X) < \infty$. Now

1. define a signed measure by $\nu(A) := \psi(\chi_A)$ and use the theorem of Radon-Nikodym to get an integrable function such that $\psi(\chi_A) = \int \chi_A f \, d\mu$.
2. Next, it follows from linearity that the $\psi(g) = \int \chi_A g \, d\mu$ for all simple measurable functions g.
3. Arrive at $\|f\|_p \leq \|\psi\| < \infty$ by dividing the problem
   into the cases $p = 1$ and $1 < p < \infty$.
4. Prove the theorem for $\sigma$-finite measures.

In all of the above proofs, we show at the start of part 3. that
\begin{equation}\label{main}
\psi(g) = \int f g \, d\mu \quad \quad (1)
\end{equation}
holds for all $g \in L^\infty \subset L^q$.
This is confusing to me, because we can show more easily
that the statement holds for all $g \in L^q$ (since compactly supported simple measurable functions are dense in $L^q$): just use the continuity of $\psi$ on the left-hand side and the monotone convergence theorem on the right. I know that $L^\infty \subset L^q$
for finite measures, but I am having trouble finding where the statement $(1)$ for
$g \in L^\infty$ actually comes into play in the proof.

Since I highly doubt that three good proofs would all preform the same (for me seemingly
unnecessary) step, I conclude that I missed something in part 3. of the proof. Therefore,
I would be grateful if anyone could give me a hint as to where $(1)$ is actually used
for $g \in L^\infty$.

Comment: How are you using the monotone convergence theorem? $f$ doesn't have a sign and, as far as I can tell, up to this point the only integrability of $f$ that you have is $L^1$ (you're trying to improve this to $L^p$ in step 3), so this forces you to test against $L^\infty$ functions.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, at this point all we know is that $f \in L^1$, let us assume that $f \geq 0$ and take a monotone sequence of simple functions $(f_k) \in L^p$ so that $0 \leq f_k \leq f$ and $\lim f_k = f$. Then $f_k^p \to f^p$ and by monotone convergence we get $\int |f|^p d\mu = \lim \int |f_k|^p d\mu$.

Comment: @BBMBR And how are you going to show that $\lim \int|f_k|^p\,d\mu < \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying Radon Nikodym, you have $f \in L^1(X, \mu)$ such that for all simple functions $g$,
$$\psi(g) = \int_{X}fg\,d\mu.$$
Now what you want to show is that $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$ and that the above holds for all $g \in L^q(X, \mu)$. Your suggestion is to somehow make use of a density argument, I guess by showing that both sides act continuously on $L^q(X, \mu)$. The problem is that you don't even know whether the right hand side is well defined when $g \in L^q(X, \mu)$, that is, whether $fg \in L^1(X, \mu)$. This would be true if $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$, but you don't know that either. However if you can establish that $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$, then the proof goes through.

Right now all you know is that if $g$ is a simple function, then $fg \in L^1(X, \mu)$, and $|\int_{X}fg\,d\mu| \leq \lVert \phi \rVert \lVert g \rVert_{L^q}$. The usual proofs show that these estimates imply $\lVert f \rVert_{L^p} \leq \lVert \phi \rVert$. This is exactly the approach taken by Folland.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can see that it's uncomfortable to use a convergence theorem here. Maybe what trips me up is that all proofs show that $\psi(g)$ is as expected for $g \in L^\infty$, which then implies the same for $g \in L^q$, but I concede that it might be more difficult to show for $g \in L^q$ than for $g\in L^\infty$.